# How to transform a string vector to character array

Tags: r, string

```
> head(base_mat)
                                                                                                     V1
1 CTGCAGAGGCTATTTCCTGGAATGAATCAACGAGTGAAACGAATAACTCTATGGTGACTGAATTCATTTTTCTGGGTCTCTCTGATTCTCAGGAACTCCAG
2 TCTGCTGTGAGGCAGACGTTGGGACTGTAGAGGCTGACGGGAGGCAGAGGCTGGGCCTGGAGGGGCCACCAAGATGCAGGAGCTGGGCCTGGAGAGGCTGC
3 CATAATCACAATTTCCTCCCCATTTTCTTAGTTCTCATAATTTTAGCCACAGCCCAGTTGGCTGGACCAATGGATGGAGAGAATCACTCAGTGGTATCTGA
4 TCAGATACCACTGAGTGATTCTCTCCATCCATTGGTCCAGCCAACTGGGCTGTGGCTAAAATTATGAGAACTAAGAAAATGGGGAGGAAATTGTGATTATG
5 CCAAATACCTGCACAGTATGTATGATAAATGCATATGATAAAGTAAAAAAAAAAATAGCACACACTGAAAGAAAGCCAACAGAAGAGGGCACTGGGCATGG
6 TTGAGCTGGGATTATAGTTGACATTTCATTATAATATATTAGCTATTCTAGACTTTATGCATTTATGTAAAGTTTTCTTTGTTGCACTTTAAGTTCTGTGA
```

I want to transform it to character array, but the `strsplit()` function doesn't work.

```
> strsplit(head(base_mat),split="")
Error in strsplit(head(base_mat), split = "") : 非字符参数
```

I want every column of the string to be a variable of data.frame. 
such as

```
V1    V2    V3
C     T     G   ...
T     C     T
...
```

How to do that?

Comment: The most likely culprit is that you are working with a factor variable and have to use `as.character` to coerce the variable prior to using `strsplit`.

Comment: Can you do a dput of base_mat?

Comment: `x <- "CTGCAGAGGCTATTTCCTGGAATGAATCAACGAGTGAAACGAATAAC";
strsplit(x, "")` use the empty string in `split=` in `strsplit()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Imo for reminding me the `factor` variable question and @jogo for the solution.  My problem can be fixed as follows.

```
> options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> x <- c("CTGCAGAGGCTATTTCCTGGAATGAATCAACGAGTGAAACGAATAAC","CTGCAGAGGCTATTTCCTGGAATGAATCAACGAGTGAAACGAATAAC")
> x <- data.frame(x)
> strsplit(x, "")
Error in strsplit(x, "") : non-character argument
> strsplit(x[,1], "")
[[1]]
 [1] "C" "T" "G" "C" "A" "G" "A" "G" "G" "C" "T" "A"
[13] "T" "T" "T" "C" "C" "T" "G" "G" "A" "A" "T" "G"
[25] "A" "A" "T" "C" "A" "A" "C" "G" "A" "G" "T" "G"
[37] "A" "A" "A" "C" "G" "A" "A" "T" "A" "A" "C"

[[2]]
 [1] "C" "T" "G" "C" "A" "G" "A" "G" "G" "C" "T" "A"
[13] "T" "T" "T" "C" "C" "T" "G" "G" "A" "A" "T" "G"
[25] "A" "A" "T" "C" "A" "A" "C" "G" "A" "G" "T" "G"
[37] "A" "A" "A" "C" "G" "A" "A" "T" "A" "A" "C"
```